# Updating a retrieved Firestore document?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-firestore

I'm stumbling onto an issue which I find silly, but can't seem to get around:

I'm not directly able to update the documents which I retrieve from Firestore. For example, when I try the deploy the following code within a onWrite trigger to a different node:

```
admin.firestore().collection("user-data").doc('someUserId').get().then(doc => {
      const profile = doc.data()

      if (profile.foo != 'bar') {
        return 0
      }

      return doc.update({
        objectToUpdate: {
          fieldToUpdate: 'Foo is not bar!'}
        })
```

I get the error that `doc.update is not a function`

I've also tried `doc.ref.update`, and `doc.data.ref.update`, but no dice.

I can achieve what I want with `admin.firestore().collection("user-data').doc('someUserId').update({...})`, but that just feels so clunky...

What am I missing here?

Comment: I've the similar issue. I'm getting the document by using where condition and I want to update that document. The retrieved document ain't being updated. I think the API does not support that as yet. We need a ref to the document and only then it can update.

Comment: Infact I tried using doc.ref and the document gotten updated succesfully. Did not work with doc.update directly

Comment: you don't need to get().  Change .get() to update({ stuff to update}) .  update() returns a promise.  You'll can get rid of a lot of the code in your then() statement in your example.